# ¿Cómo puedo hacer UPDATE en Firebird desde JavaScript donde me actualice solo el primer registro que encuentre, ya que algunos registros se repiten?

Tags: javascript, sql, update, firebird

Tengo aquí la función pero me lanza errores, la función esta bien incluso el UPDATE también pero a la hora de indicarle que solo actualice el primer registro que encuentre no se puede, si le quito el FIRST 1, si me actualiza los datos pero me actualiza todos los id de la tabla que encuentre ya que existen registros con id iguales pero con el campo Existencia diferente.

Las versiones de las dependencias y db son:
"node-firebird": "^1.1.5"
Firebird 3.0

````
const segunda_consulta = (elementos) => {
    console.log(elementos);
    const currentDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    Firebird.attach(options, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: 'Error connecting to the database'});
        }

        const promises = elementos.map((registro) => {
            
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.execute("UPDATE FIRST 1 CAPAS_COSTOS SET EXISTENCIA = EXISTENCIA - ? WHERE ARTICULO_ID = ?",[registro.diferencia,registro.articulo_id], (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(`Error executing UPDATE query for articulo_id ${registro.articulo_id}:`, err);
                        reject(err);
                    }else{
                        resolve()
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
            db.detach((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error detaching from the database:', err);
                }
                console.log('se insertaron las direfencias en la db');
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error('Error executing queries:', err);
        });
    });
    
}; ```
````

Comment: mmm... no tienes otro campo que haga único el registro que quieres actualizar?

Comment: No, incluso podría ser la fecha, pero tampoco, los registros repetidos, tienen el mismo id la misma fecha pero las existencias diferentes?

Comment: De todos los que tienen el mismo `articulo_id`, ¿cómo sabes cuál es el que quieres actualizar?

Comment: podrían ser las existencias que están mas cercanas a cero o evaluar si el campo existencia es menor 10 que loa actualice, tengo que intentarlo

Comment: Si la tabla tiene una llave primaria, incluye la estructura en la pregunta. La actualización tiene que ser necesariamente en dos pasos. Podrías dejarlo en un procedimiento almacenado. Si no tiene llave primaria, debiera tener al menos un índice único. Si no tiene ninguno de los dos, no veo la manera de hacerlo de una manera segura y eficiente.